# Getting an error.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
package RoughWork;

import com.omnitech.util.Xls_Reader;

public class TestDataExtract2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xls_Reader x = new Xls_Reader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\omnitech\\xls\\TestSuiteA.xlsx");     
        getData(x,"TestCase_1");

    }

    public static Object[][] getData(Xls_Reader xls, String testCaseName){
        if(! xls.isSheetExist("TestCase_1")){
            xls=null;
            return new Object [1][0]; 
        }

        int rows = xls.getRowCount("TestCase_1");
        int col = xls.getColumnCount("TestCase_1");
        //System.out.println("rows are --" + rows);
        //System.out.println("col are --" + col);

        Object[][] data = new Object[rows-1][col-4];
        for(int rowNum=2;rowNum<=rows;rowNum++){
            for(int colNum=0;colNum<=col-3;colNum++){

                data[rowNum-1][colNum] = xls.getCellData(testCaseName,rowNum, colNum);
                //System.out.print(xls.getCellData(testCaseName, colNum, rowNum)+"--");{
                    //System.out.println();
                }
            }


        return data;

    }


}
```

I am not able to execute the above code and if i try to debug i don't get any result.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at RoughWork.TestDataExtract2.getData(TestDataExtract2.java:28)
 at RoughWork.TestDataExtract2.main(TestDataExtract2.java:9)

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your problem in the **for loop** :

**first** : you start loop from `rowNum = 2` and first index in your array will be `rowNum - 1` which mean you will start from index `1` not `0`

**second** : number of column in your data array is `col - 4`
if we assume `col = 6` so `no. of column = 6-4=2`
and your for loop : from `0` to `col-3=3` (and you have only 2 element in the data col)----> so here you will get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`